# Fetching from google api is not working correctly?

Tags: react-native

**Problem:**

I am creating a react native application.T here I have used Google API to get nearby places for that I have write fetch request like this.

```
fetch(
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location" +
        coords.latitude +
        "," +
        coords.longitude +
        "&radius=1500"+
        "&type=restaurant" +
        "&key=" +
        apikey
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log(responseJson);
      });
```

It is giving me a response like this.

```
[09:04:15] Object {
[09:04:15]   "html_attributions": Array [],
[09:04:15]   "results": Array [],
[09:04:15]   "status": "INVALID_REQUEST",
[09:04:15] }
```

Can Someone help me to solve this problem?. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you missing an equals sign (`=`) after `json?location` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, try it with an equals sign like this:

```
fetch(
  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" +
    coords.latitude +
    "," +
    coords.longitude +
    "&radius=1500"+
    "&type=restaurant" +
    "&key=" +
    apikey
)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson => {
    console.log(responseJson);
  });
```